Why Is Memory usage Undefined When Capturing Memory Stats from a Docker Container in Node.js?
I'm developing a Node.js application that runs user-submitted code in Docker containers using the Dockerode library. I'm trying to capture the memory usage of the running container, but I always get memUsage as undefined.
Here’s the relevant part of my code where I attempt to capture the memory stats:
// Start capturing memory stats
const statsStream = await container.stats({ stream: true });
const statsPromise = new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
    statsStream.on("data", (data) => {
        const stats = JSON.parse(data.toString("utf8"));
        if (stats.memory_stats) {
            memUsage = stats.memory_stats.usage / (1024 * 1024); // Memory usage in MB
            console.log("Memory usage:", stats.memory_stats.usage);
        }
    });

    statsStream.on("end", () => resolve());
});

Current Issues:
memUsage remains undefined, and I cannot figure out why the memory usage stats are not being populated.

memUsage remains undefined, and I cannot figure out why the memory usage stats are not being populated.

I'm unsure if I'm correctly parsing the stats data from the Docker API.


Questions:

How can I ensure that memory_stats is available in the emitted data from the stats stream?

What should I log to debug this issue effectively?

Are there any additional configurations or considerations I should be aware of when using memory limits in Docker


Here’s a simplified version of my code that demonstrates the issue:
const statsStream = await container.stats({ stream: true });
statsStream.on("data", (data) => {
    const stats = JSON.parse(data.toString("utf8"));
    console.log("Stats Data:", stats); // Log the entire stats object
});


Assuming container as being your Docker api, then maybe the problem lies in your Docker configuration (not talking about your container configuration but Docker itself). Aparently it is not populating your peformance statistics or something like that... I'm not really a specialist on Docker (just have superficial knowledge)..
